VS Code not updating: Failed to create file handle: system cannot find the path specified
VS Code was unable to update with an error message stating that "There was an error while Opening file handle: "C:\Users\\AppData\.....\....
[Similar issue regarding files being in use][1] didn't resolve the issue.  In my case an extension had failed to install properly, and left a bad reference behind.

Running the updater manually in admin mode was no help: as per the error message there was a bad reference in AppData.
Reinstalling vscode also didn't work for the same reason.
Removing a reference to the offending plugin in ...\AppData\Local\Programs\\\Extensions\extensions.json also didn't resolve the issue.
Uninstalling, deleting the vscode folder in AppData, then reinstalling resolved the issue.

For me, downloading the official installer and running it solved this issue. (w/ installer v1.92.0)
